# Cancelling runaway JavaScript timeouts/intervals within a revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, module, instance, settimeout, setinterval

I have a fairly standardised revealing module pattern to create objects for use as instances. Sometimes, within these patterns there are timeouts or intervals that need to be cancelled in the case that the module is no longer being used or referenced within external code.

Simplified example of this pattern:

```js
function test() {
    window.timer = maketimer();
}

function maketimer() {
    var cls, my;

    my = {
        increment: 0,
        timerid: null,

        exec_timer: function() {
            my.timerid = window.setInterval(my.time, 2000);
        },

        time: function() {
            console.log("timer: ", my.timerid, my.increment++);
        }
    },

    cls = {
        //...
    }

    my.exec_timer();

    return cls;
};

test();

// some time later...
test();
```

In the case that `test` is called twice, for whatever reason, the variable `window.timer` is replaced with a second instance of `maketimer` but the first instance timer continues to run.

A lot of the time, my modules are intrinsically linked to DOM nodes, and more often than not the DOM nodes are removed with the old instances, so I could in theory check for the non-existence of the node or its placement outside of the DOM, and then cancel the interval in this case.

This is far more generic however, and I would like to be able to deal with timeouts outside of the DOM environment.

Comment: You asked for when the module is no longer referenced but `setInterval` creates a reference...

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the interval reference - that's easy to remove. the issue is regarding there being no way (to my knowledge) of testing that the module instance is still "active" (`window.timer`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would wrap the whole function in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) that contains an `instance` variable. In it, you save the timer. And every time a new one is started, the old one is destroyed:

```
(function(window) {
    var timerInstance = null;

    window.maketimer = function() {
        var cls, my;

        if(timerInstance) {
            timerInstance.destroyInstance();
        }

        my = {
            increment: 0,
            timerid: null,

            exec_timer: function() {
                my.timerid = window.setInterval(my.time, 2000);
            },

            time: function() {
                console.log("timer: ", my.timerid, my.increment++);
            },
            destroyInstance: function() {
                window.clearInterval(my.timerid);
            }
        },

        cls = {
            //...
        }

        my.exec_timer();

        timerInstance = my;

        return cls;
    }
})(window);

function test() {
    window.timer = maketimer();
}

test();
test();
```

Just out of curiosity, why do you need to have the instance on a global variable? `window.timer` is pretty generic and could be overridden by other scripts.

Comment: Yeah - this is the only real answer to this problem I could think of as well - exposing a method for the purpose of clearing any timers stored internally in the case that the instance reference (`window.timer`) already exists. The problem then is that if (for instance) this was a third party library or the code was being maintained by another developer, awareness of this method is mandatory and the issue might remain - and worse yet, occur invisibly.

Comment: In answer to your other question, `window.timer` is just for this example. I'd normally use the correct namespacing, encapsulation, etc.

Comment: Do you only always want a single instance to exist? In that case, there might be another solution (actually, it works for multiple instances as well).

Comment: For the purposes of this use case, yes. The code in question is replacing an instance with another instance after an XHR for new DOM markup completes, applying said instances to the newly created markup.

Comment: I realise this may not be a `setTimeout/Interval` issue at all - and more one of defensive instance management. However, it would be useful to know if an 'automated' clearing of timers within a deceased instance is even possible within JS.

Comment: I don't know about calling a function on garbage collection. `setInterval` isn't specifically bound to the object from `maketimer`, so it wont be garbage collected as long is the timer runs. I updated the code to show a possible solution though, thus just keeping your instance private and clearing it when a new timer is started.

Comment: Thank you! This has helped a lot, and it hadn't occured to me to use an IIFE with closure in this case. I've set your answer as accepted as it's cleaner than my further example below, which explains how to do the same thing when tying instances to multiple DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it: Update your code below..

```
var settimer;
function test() {
   clearTimeout(settimer);
   settimer= setTimeout(function () { 
      window.timer = maketimer(); 
   }, 100);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the only effect this has is to call `maketimer` once. The issue here is specific to when the object is instantiated more than once over a long period of time. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [answer given by @nils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33344747/5488860), I've created the below example for constructing a module which takes in a single DOM node and will only clear the previous instance/timer if the DOM node has already been used:

```
<div id="element1">[code here that may be updated with XHR]</div>
<div id="element2">[code here that may be updated with XHR]</div>
```

```js
(function(window) {
    var timerInstances = [];

    window.maketimer = function(element) {
        var cls, my, a;

        // find instances where the passed element matches
        for (a = 0; a < timerInstances.length; a += 1) {
            if (timerInstances[a].element === element) {
                console.log("instance already exists for element", element, "destroying...");
                timerInstances[a].in.destroyInstance();
            }
        }

        my = {
            increment: 0,
            timerid: null,

            exec_timer: function() {
                my.timerid = window.setInterval(my.time, 2000);
            },

            time: function() {
                console.log("timer: ", my.timerid, my.increment++);
            },

            destroyInstance: function() {
                window.clearInterval(my.timerid);
            }
        },

        cls = {
            //...
        }

        my.exec_timer();

        timerInstances.push({
            'element': element,
            'in': my
        });

        return cls;
    }
})(window);

function test(element) {
    window.timer = maketimer(element);
}

test(document.getElementById("element1")); // produces 1 timer
test(document.getElementById("element1")); // cancels last, produces 1 timer
test(document.getElementById("element2")); // produces 1 timer
```

The identifying argument could be anything here - in this case it's a DOM node, but it could easily be a Number, String etc.

The accepted answer is very helpful and is still preferred if you wish to maintain the rule of having one instance at a time on the document.